# MDBs consume remote JMS pub/sub provider.. can anyone show me n simple example

Tags: java, jms, message-driven-bean

I'm developing an MDB to consume a pub/sub provider from remote JMS, I have no idea about it.
can anyone show me a simple helloworld example of the whole process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider taking a look at the Spring-Integration project.  If you're new to Spring there might be a bit of a learning curve, but in the end this project really makes developing pub/sub applications simple.
[Spring Integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration)